# Same page different sections

Tags: information-architecture

i'm designing a a site an i need to use a page across the site's inside subsections ,

i'm trying with several approaches but don't want to mess the breadcrumb navigation , and i also don't want to duplicate this page 3 times, how can i handle it?

site.com\
         section a\
                    content a
                    common page
         section b\
                    content b
                    common page
         section c\
                  content c
                  common page

Answer (score 3):

While there's A LOT of information needed, it seems to me you're facing a classic IA problem: the dreaded *this item belongs to everyone* approach. And again, I don't have the information, but in most cases, the problem is that the IA is wrong.

See, you always need to *think in terms of hierarchies and levels*. So, let's say you have 3 categories (small biz, enterprises, government) for which you have a common element, let's say a service (*using this example because it's pretty common and I feel like your case must be similar*). According to your question, you have this structure:

[image]

This will obviously break any breadcrumb or tree or whatever, because once you get to *service*... where do you get back to?

As you may see, ***service* is the common element**, so you should try something like this:

[image]

Now you can easily get back to the original page.

Or, put in other simply and easy to remember words: ***a branch never becomes a root***